# How can I get data from database in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to be able to get data from database.

I need table named `role_users`, column `role_id`
and table `functions`, column `function`.

**Here is my View:**

```
@foreach($contact_users as $contact)

<a   href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $contact->username }}">{{ $contact->username  }}</a></h3>
        <p>
            <strong><i class="icon-real-estate-020 u-line-icon-pro"></i> : </strong><a  href="#">{{ $contact->country }}</a><br>
        <strong><i class="icon-screen-tablet fa-" aria-hidden="true"></i> : </strong><a href="#">{{ $contact->industry }}</a><br>
        <strong><i class="icon-frame fa-" aria-hidden="true"></i> : </strong><a href="#">{{ $contact->organization_type }}</a><br>

@endforeach
```

**and here is my Controller:**

```
$data['contact_users'] = DB::table('contacts')
             ->join('users' , 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.contact_id')
             ->join('industries' , 'industries.id', '=', 'users.industry_id')
             ->join('countries' , 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
             ->join('organization_types' , 'organization_types.id', '=', 'users.organization_type_id')
                    ->select('users.*','industries.industry','countries.country','organization_types.organization_type')
             ->where('contacts.contact_id','!=',$id)
             ->where('users.deleted_at','=',NULL)
             ->whereIn('contacts.user_id', $contact_id)
             ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $contact_id)
             ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $inviter_id)
             ->groupBy('contact_id')
             ->take(4)
             ->get();
```

I want to add function below `organization_type`.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using DB query joins?

You need to define your Models first then you can have clearer queries using Eloquent. Please look at the documentation for more.

(https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent